# am vs will be free for four days

Tags: future-tense

I am going to make up two similar sentences below.

(1) Next week, I **am** free for four days.

(2) Next week, I **will be** free for four days.

A few of my neighbors are native English speakers. They think (2) is not idiomatic. I wonder why it isn't. "Next week" is temporal point in the future. Why can't I use "will be"?

Comment: Both of those sound fine to me. Perhaps you should ask them why they don’t think it’s idiomatic, and tell us what they say.

Comment: On the reverse side, (2) sounds more reasonable to me than (1) because the time is given.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences would commonly be used, but they have different nuances.

"Next week, I am free for four days" is essentially a reference to your calendar or schedule.  At the present time ("am"), I have nothing scheduled for four days next week.

"Next week, I will be free for four days" refers directly to you.  Next week (future), you "will" be free four days.